# Access currentOp through Java Mongo 3.4 driver or Spring Data Mongo

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

I'm trying run the following through the Java Mongo driver or spring

```
db.currentOp(
 {
  "active" : true,
  "secs_running" : { "$gt" : 3 }
 }
);
```

and

```
db.currentOp(true);
```

I'm using

- Java 8
- Mongo Java Driver 3.4.3
- Spring Data Mongo 1.10.6
- Mongo 3.4.9

Anyone know of a good way to do this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use **runCommand** method on **admin** database:

```
MongoDatabase database = client.getDatabase("admin");    
Document document1 = database.runCommand(new Document("currentOp", 1)
        .append("active", true));
Document document2 = database.runCommand(new Document("currentOp", 1)
        .append("active", false));
Document document3 = database.runCommand(new Document("currentOp", 1)
        .append("active", true)
        .append("secs_running", new Document("$gt", 3)));
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.   I tried what you proposed, but the flag on the currentOp do not seem to be honored. For instance when I say try to say active is false and running for more than 3 seconds it still returns the currently running currentOp.  The details from the query are
---
    **"active": true,**
    "opid": 15144,
    **"secs_running": 0,**
    "microsecs_running": 27,
    "op": "command",
    "ns": "admin.$cmd",
    "query": {
       **"currentOp": {**
       **"active": false,**
       **"secs_running": {**
       **"$gt": 3**
    }

Comment: I see, command `db.runCommand({currentOp: {active: false}})` even does not work from mongo shell. will investigate this issue

Comment: I figured out, we need to use the following command: `db.runCommand({"currentOp": 1, "active": true, "secs_running" : { "$gt" : 3 }})`. please try updated answer, it works for me.